# Time limit for send data with Tcl expect

Tags: smtp, send, expect

I wrote two expect script for sending email using Netcat and Telent.
With both scripts, the connection to the smtp server drop if the data
size is too long (over 100k). I guess it is an issue of timeout, because
if my connection is really fast and my script manage to send all the data
in less than 2-3 seconds, the script works successfully.

So I wonder if there is a time/size limit for the send command an a way for changing this limit.

Comment: It's not uncommon for emails to be 100kb in size, and 2-3 seconds does not seem like it would be long enough to cause a timeout.  Is it possible that you are exceeding the maximum line length for SMTP, which is 1000 characters (as per RFC821).  Does the remote just drop the connection, or does it send an error message first?  If it sends and error message, what is it?

Comment: It actually does not send any error message. The terminal shows the data transmission truncated, waits few seconds, and drop the connection and the script. The strange thing is that if I do the same with a very quick connection (then with the same content), the script successfully end and the mail is sent.

Comment: If I launch the script more than once on a normal-speed connection, it always blocks at different parts of the content. Furthermore, if I try manually to send the e-mail via Telnet, it freezes as well at some part of the data, but if I press enter it continues sending data till the message is sent.

Comment: Does this happen with only one remote host, or does this happen with multiple remote hosts?

Comment: It happens with every single remote host I tried so far. On the other hand, if use Netcat from command line (nc smpt.myserver.com 25 < myfile) instead that using an interactive expect script, the mail is sent successfully (at least with some hosts). I launch it via Linux terminal.

Comment: You might want to try running your script under tcpclient (http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpclient.html) - this will basically make your script interact to the remote host as if it was a mail client.  Output from your script will be sent through tcpclient to the remote host (on port 25), and responses back from the remote host will be piped through tcpclient to your script's stdin.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
It was a very silly bug. In my script I just expect "250" for the end of data and 
delivery accepted. But attachments are encoded in base64, and include numeric data
and usually many times 250.
So I just had to change "250" to "250 " in my script.